# Global error handling in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there a way to handle all JavaScript errors and exceptions in ExtJS application globally and route it to a function that alerts the user on a server error?

`window:onerror()` doesn't seem to handle all the JavaScript errors, hence looking for some kind of catch in the code, to wrap it in to a more generic exception so that it would be caught?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Error-static-method-handle

> Globally handle any Ext errors that may be raised, optionally
>   providing custom logic to handle different errors individually. Return
>   true from the function to bypass throwing the error to the browser,
>   otherwise the error will be thrown and execution will halt.

Example usage:

```
Ext.Error.handle = function(err) {
    if (err.someProperty == 'NotReallyAnError') {
        // maybe log something to the application here if applicable
        return true;
    }
    // any non-true return value (including none) will cause the error to be thrown
}
```

Normally an error would get handled by onerror, but returning true in Ext.Error.handle prevents that.

Also look at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-event-requestexception

Comment: Thanks, should I write it in the Application startup file? And shouldn't I use Ext.Create() to invoke this code? Or will it get invoked automatically when Exception are thrown

Comment: Yes, you should put it in app.init. You don't need Ext.create as it's a static method. It will get invoked when ext expections are raised. You probably still want onerror for non-ext exceptions.

Comment: Thank you, but my application doesn't have an app.init file. Should I add it in `launch: function()` method that is present in the `Ext.application()` JS file?

Comment: Can you please explain what does return true does? Will the request get cancelled?